# Apple Event sends Activate gives an error

Tags: c, macos, macos-carbon, appleevents

I am working on C application which uses AppleEvents.
So far I am trying to do simple example which sends Activate to the Terminal.
This is what I have:

```
int main()
{
  AppleEvent theEvent;
  char* arg = "com.apple.Terminal";
  AEAddressDesc addDesc;
  OSErr err = AECreateDesc( typeApplicationBundleID, &arg, strlen( arg ), &addDesc );
  printf("AECreateDesc error --> %d\n", err);
  if( noErr == err )
  {
    // my event creation
    // create event:
    err = AECreateAppleEvent( 'misc', 'actv', &addDesc, kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &theEvent );
  }
  printf("AECreateAppleEvent error --> %d\n", err);
  if (noErr == err)
  {
    AESendMode aeSendMode = kAEAlwaysInteract | kAEWaitReply;
    //err = AESend( &theEvent, NULL, aeSendMode, kAENormalPriority, kAEDefaultTimeout, NULL, NULL );
    err = AESendMessage(&theEvent, NULL, aeSendMode, kAEDefaultTimeout);
  }
  printf("AESend error --> %d\n", err);
  return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program it always prints AESend error --> -600 which I have seen that means process not found

Could someone tell me what is wrong here please?

Note: I do not want to use AppleScript, I want to use this, so please no recommendations about using AppleScript

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Something I would suggest is to put this code into a simple Cocoa GUI application (like in applicationDidFinishLaunching). I'm not sure that AppleEvents will work from a standalone command-line app that doesn't have a runloop or any of the normal setup of a GUI application. Also, what OS version are you running? 10.14 Mojave has some extra restrictions around AppleEvents.

Comment: `arg` is a poiniter. Is it `AECreateDesc( typeApplicationBundleID, &arg, …` or `AECreateDesc( typeApplicationBundleID, arg,` …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call:

```
OSErr err = AECreateDesc( typeApplicationBundleID, arg, strlen( arg ), &addDesc );
```

without `&`.